# How to get structlog log level?

Tags: python, structlog

Is there a way to get the effective log level of a [structlog](https://www.structlog.org/en/stable/index.html) logger? I want to do something like the following:

```
import structlog

logger = structlog.get_logger()

if logger.isEnabledFor(DEBUG):
    some_expensive_report()
```

I'm looking for something like [isEnabledFor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.isEnabledFor) from the standard library logging module. Does such a thing exist?

**Update**: It looks like I can use `logger.bind().isEnabledFor()`, but only if I configure struct log with `structlog.configure(wrapper_class=structlog.stdlib.BoundLogger)`. Is this the answer?

Comment: Are you using structlog’s built-in levels or its standard library integration?

Comment: I'm using structlog.stdlib.filter_by_level, if that's what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you use structlog's standard library integration, you can use the method proxies that you've found yourself in the end. For structlog's much faster native levels there's no such functionality yet.